# Loaderror: cannot find such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hi i have just started making an app on ruby on rails and i have problems writing my spec files. 
i ran `bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/api/user_controller_spec.rb` but it gave me the error:

```
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/action
/slidey/spec/controllers/api/user_controller_spec.rb (LoadError)                                                                        
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'      
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'                          
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'               
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'                             
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'                                   
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

EDIT: when i ran `bundle exec rspec spec` they gave me the following error:

```
/home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing': undefined method `has
_attached_file' for #<Class:0x007f44f503bee8> (NoMethodError)                                                                           
        from /home/action/slidey/app/models/documents.rb:6:in `<class:Documents>'                                                       
        from /home/action/slidey/app/models/documents.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'                                                        
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'                  
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'         
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'          
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'                  
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'          
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'    
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'            
        from /home/action/slidey/spec/models/documents_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'                                                  
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'                     
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'            
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'          
        from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
```

can anyone shed some light on this? what does it mean?

Comment: it should be users_controller, not user_controller

Comment: Are you using Paperclip? Is the gem installed? Does the controller work in development but not in test?

Comment: @Avdept hi ive changed to users_controller but it still doesnt work...

Comment: @zetetic nope not using paperclip... but would it be better if i tried paperclip?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it cannot find the file `spec/controllers/api/user_controller_spec.rb`

Comment: erm. nope. i ran that file and it works. thank u for attempting :)

Comment: Do all the specs run fine when you use `bundle exec rspec`?

Comment: hi i've attached what i saw when i run bundle exec rspec spec in the question as edit!

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your spec file into `users_controller_spec.rb`

Comment: @Avdept hi thank u for your reply but it still doesnt work... D':

Comment: Try to post list of files in your app/controllers folder and spec/controllers